# Magento Catalog Rules not working after sometime

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog-rules

I have discount on products of particular brand(eg. nike) for logged in users. Its works fine when I click on Save and Apply but after some time it not shows discount price for products.

I have created custom cron page to apply the catalog rules

```
$catalogPriceRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
$catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');
```

I am confused by searching, and I don't find any correct answer.